# How to disable a plugin for certain page?

Tags: plugins, filters

I tried this (inserted into the function.php):

```
if( is_page( 799 ) ) {
  remove_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'bj_lazy_load' );
}
```

Not working...

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774424/wordpress-disable-plugin-on-specific-pages-posts/) post?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with this? It sounds like bad practice

Answer (score 1):

`functions.php` file is loaded after the `plugins_loaded` hook is fired. So you are (probably) removing the hook, but it's already fired, so it doesn't really matter.

If you want to remove a hook, you need to know when the hook was added. Then you need to remove the action at a later time, but before that hook is fired.